# How to remove error in opening xml file in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxml, nsxmldocument

To start with Cocoa xml read write coding I have created a sample application, where I am able to write into XML file but getting some errors in reading. Below is the code for that.

```
NSXMLElement * root = [[NSXMLElement alloc ] initWithName:@"Book"]
NSXMLDocument * xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc ] initWithRootElement: root ];
[root addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName: @"Name" stringValue:@"book name"]];
[root addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"Author" stringValue:@"bool author"]];
 NSData * xmlData = [xmlDoc XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
[xmlData writeToFile:[@"~/Desktop/book.xml" stringByExpandingTildeInPath ]
 atomically:YES];
[xmlDoc release ];
```

This works fine and book.xml is created.
But when tried to read this file, I am facing issues in opening this file.
Here is the code for that.

```
NSString *strValue = [@"~/Desktop/book.xml" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSURL * strUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:strValue];
NSError * err = nil;
NSXMLDocument  * xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:strUrl    
options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:&err];
NSXMLNode * rootNode = [xmlDoc rootElement ];
[xmlDoc release ];
```

value of xmlDoc is nil.

Your answers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tausif.

Comment: The err says - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1014 "zero byte resource".

Comment: And the `book.xml` file was really written? When you do expand tilde, also prepend `file://` to your `strValue`.

Comment: Wow.... It worked ....    just for curiosity what is the importance of file://, since I am new to the Mac development.  Thanks a lot for your  quick response to make it possible.

Comment: I'll write more in the answer box, mmt ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `file://` in `strValue`. See `NSURL` class documentation ... If you don't want to mess with prepending `file://` manually, you should use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`.

Why all this?

Simplified explanation for your case - every URL does consist of scheme/protocol (http, file, https, ...), delimiter (://) and path (~/Desktop/...). And it's mandatory, not optional. When you do use `URLWithString:` it expects that your string is complete URL, not just part of it (missing scheme/protocol in your case).

So, if you do want to use URL instead of file path, you have to take care of `file://` (when `URLWithString:` is used) or do use `fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` where you can pass just file path.

You do this, but just warning for others, if your path does contain tilde (~) you must expand it first.

Comment: In the case of `NSXMLDocument` there is a `initWithData:` method that you can used if you don't want to use URLs e.g: `[[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file"] options:0 error:NULL]`

Comment: Ok right now I am fine with this, still I will try with one more which you have mentioned.